# JQuery Carousel website - need advice

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

OK doing a "fixed height design" microsite for a client;

**Situation**

At present I have built it in HTML with normal hyperlinks as Nav.

Underneath the fixed height content is a scrollbar, as they want to be able to have Carousel slidy through the pages from the homepage.

Obviously on visiting the omepage, I'm going to need to AJAX in the next possible pages.  Clicking on a hyperlink nav, will slide the carousel to that page content.

Despite my objections for many reasons they want to proceed with the idea.

**Mission**

Has anyone tried this idea for a slidy flash site but in HTML?

What jQuery carousel plugins can be bastedised? My experience with Carousel is it needs all the elements in the page to initialise, how will ajaxing in new elements be handled...

I'm not quite as experienced coder to do my own carousel plugin with the complexity of AJAX and error handling.

Anyone got an ideas how they would tackle it or direction as to where to start?!?

P.S. Sorry this is vague, anhd may be more of a discussion than a Q and A.

Cheers, Will

Comment: can u add a link or a image for your set of requirments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the carousel, in my experience jQuery Cycle plugin works with AJAX-content. I've used it, liked it. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

With Cycle plugin you have arrows for page-changing. It seems to have a parameters

```
pager:         null,  // selector for element to use as pager container 
pagerAnchorBuilder: null, // callback fn for building anchor links:  function(index, DOMelement) 
pagerEvent:    'click.cycle', // name of event which drives the pager navigation
```

So it might work for your needs.

I'm not sure I understand your layout exactly, but if you just need to scroll it sideways, just give a container a fixed width & overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at that.  They want carousel behaviour, so From 'Home' the next arrow moves the content area to 'About us' then 'Contact us' etc. However it is a little more complicated with 30-50 odd pages and nested navigation.  Just worry about too many DOM elements and the browser crashing contantly.